# Grub corrupted and etc directory missing

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, filesystem

I have a dual installation with Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows 7. I was in windows, I had to restart my machine and my grub was not loading. I used boot-repair to load my grub. However, my linux installation had a file system corrupt due to some not safe restart. So I was trying to do fsck from Live CD. However, after the the check says everything is fine, when I mounted the partition, my etc directory in my linux partition root directory has become a file. Further, this lead to my grub not getting loaded and bunch of failures after that as /etc is important to purge and reinstall a grub.

Can someone help me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you can reinstall your grub from rescue mode..
you went in the rescue mode of your HDD os using another os. 
now # chroot /mnt/sysimage/ enter
now # grub-install /dev/sda
now your grub will be restore now the next problem of etc dir missing can be recover from tar or fronm other same os you can copy from it..